# Snap Back component on clicking back button

Tags: reactjs

I have route '/Book'. And i am displaying recently played list when user clicks on any recently played book. BookDetail component opens up which has book details on the same page and same route i.e '/Book'
I have provided back button on top left corner. Desired behavior is when a user clicks on this back button this component should snap back. It should appear only when user clicks on any book.

Here is what i tried to useState and on clicking to change state, but its not working as desired.  I am using react-router-dom v 6.16

Here is the code

```
import { Grid, Paper, Typography, IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import { ArrowBack, Language } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from '../../app/store/configureStore';
import NotFound from '../../app/errors/NotFound';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
import LoadingComponent from '../../app/layout/LoadingComponent';
import { productSelectors } from './bookSlice';
import { fetchMediumAsync, mediumSelector } from '../medium/mediumSlice';
import useProducts from '../../app/hooks/useProducts';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


interface Props {
  bk_ID: string;
}

export default function BookDetail({ bk_ID }: Props) {
  const { productsLoaded } = useProducts();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const product = useAppSelector(state => productSelectors.selectById(state, bk_ID!));
  const[snap, setSnap] = useState(false);


  if (!productsLoaded) return <LoadingComponent message='Loading books...' />;

  if (!product) {
    return <NotFound />;
  }

  const { bk_Name = ''} = product;


  const trimmedTitle = product.bk_Title.length > 22 ? product.bk_Title.substring(0, 22) + '...' : product.bk_Title;
  const trimmedSummary = product.bk_Summary.length > 800 ? product.bk_Summary.substring(0, 800) + '...' : product.bk_Summary;

  const shouldFetchAudio = product.media[0].md_ID !== null;

  const medium = useAppSelector(state => mediumSelector.selectById(state, product?.media[0].md_ID || '')); 

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldFetchAudio && product.media[0].md_ID && !medium) {
      dispatch(fetchMediumAsync(product.media[0].md_ID));
    }
  }, [dispatch, product.media[0].md_ID, medium, shouldFetchAudio]);

  const handleBackClick = () => {
    setSnap(true)
  };

  return (
    <Paper sx={{ padding: 2, width: '100%', position: 'sticky', top: '20px', alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
      {/* Top Bar */}
      <Grid container justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center" mb={2}>
        {/* Back Button */}
        <IconButton component={Link} to='/Book' onClick={() => handleBackClick}>
          <ArrowBack />
        </IconButton>
        {/* Language Icon */}
        <IconButton>
          <Language />
        </IconButton>
      </Grid>

      {/* Book Title */}
      <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold',  position: 'absolute', top:80, right: 20}}>{trimmedTitle}</Typography>

      {/* Book Image */}
      <img src={product.media[0]?.downloadURL} alt={bk_Name} style={{ width: '30%', height: '10%', maxWidth: 200, marginTop: 1, marginBottom: 1 }} />

      {/* Book Author */}
      <Typography variant="subtitle1" sx={{ position: 'absolute', top:120, right: 20}}>{product.authors[0]?.at_Name_Ar}</Typography>

      {/* Book Description */}
      <Typography variant="body1"  sx={{ marginTop: 1, fontSize: 'small' }}>{trimmedSummary}</Typography>

      {/* Audio Player */}
      <Paper variant="outlined" sx={{ padding: 2, marginTop: 1 }}>
        {/* React Player */}
        {shouldFetchAudio ? (
          <ReactPlayer 
            url={medium?.downloadURL}
            controls={true} 
            playing={true}
            width="100%" 
            height="50px" 
        />
        ) : (
          <div>
            Book Audio: <p>NA</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </Paper>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```